# Videogular dynamically loaded video is not playable

Tags: angular, electron, videogular2

I'm using `"electron": "19.0.4"`, `"@angular/core": "13.2.4"` and  `"@videogular/ngx-videogular": "5.0.1`.

On my jukebox, when a human song request is done, the song is downloadeded, and request.song.location is updated to "file://whatever".
Only when it´s totally downloaded I dynamically create a component with this:

```
  <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onReady($event)">
    <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
    <video #media
           [vgMedia]="$any(media)"
           crossorigin
           preload="auto">
      <source [src]="request.song.location" height="auto" id="{{request.song.name}}" type="video/mp4" width="100%">
    </video>
  </vg-player>
```

On the HTML source, I can see the source src correctly updated.
And when it triggers the onReady

```
  onReady(api: VgApiService) {
    this.player = api;
    this.media = player.getDefaultMedia();
    console.log('MEDIA', this.media);
    this.player.play();
```

When the song is played, I just can see a spinning wheel, and on the log
the media has the `canPlay: false`

```
VgMediaDirective {api: VgApiService, 
ref: ViewRef$1, state: 'paused', time: {…}, buffer: {…}, …}
api: VgApiService {medias: {…},
 playerReadyEvent: EventEmitter_, 
isPlayerReady: true, 
videogularElement: vg-player.ng-tns-c280-6, fsAPI: VgFullscreenApiService}
buffer: {end: 0}
bufferDetected: Subject {closed: false, observers: Array(1), isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null}
canPlay: false
canPlayObs: SafeSubscriber {initialTeardown: undefined, closed: false, _parentage: null, _teardowns: Array(1), isStopped: false, …}
canPlayThrough: false
canPlayThroughObs: SafeSubscriber {initialTeardown: undefined, closed: false, _parentage: null, _teardowns: Array(1), isStopped: false, …}
checkInterval: 200
currentPlayPos: 0
elem: video
```

If the file is not downloaded, because it´s already on the song.location route. Then I have no problems. This code was working previously on an Electron 8 , Angular 7 with the original videogular. Any idea how to fix it? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily there's a hacky way to solve the issue, just by wrapping the  whole vg-player element with this:

```
<div *ngIf="request.song.location.length">
```

https://github.com/videogular/ngx-videogular/issues/97